# Firebird truncate table / delete all rows

Tags: sql, firebird, sql-delete, truncate

I am using Firebird 2.5.1 Embedded. I have done the usual to empty the table with nearly 200k rows:

```
delete from SZAFKI
```

Here's the output, see as it takes 16 seconds, which is, well, unacceptable.

```
Preparing query: delete from SZAFKI
Prepare time: 0.010s
PLAN (SZAFKI NATURAL)

Executing...
Done.
3973416 fetches, 1030917 marks, 116515 reads, 116434 writes.
0 inserts, 0 updates, 182658 deletes, 27 index, 182658 seq.
Delta memory: -19688 bytes.
SZAFKI: 182658 deletes. 
182658 rows affected directly.
Total execution time: 16.729s
Script execution finished.
```

Firebird has no TRUNCATE keyword. As the query uses  PLAN NATURAL, I tried to PLAN the query by hand, like so:

```
delete from szafki PLAN (SZAFKI INDEX (SZAFKI_PK))
```

but Firebird says "SZAFKI_PK cannot be used in the specified plan" (it is a primary key)
Question is how do i empty table efficiently? Dropping and recreating is not possible.

Comment: "Dropping and recreating is not possible." Why not?

Comment: Do you have triggers ON DELETE for a specified table?

Comment: Drop constraints (PK and FK) then delete data, then recreate constraints.

Comment: Plan is not useful for deletion without a `WHERE` condition: it will need to scan the entire table anyway, and because of the orientation of data in Firebird, following the index order will even hurt because it will be a random walk through all pages of a table, instead of scanning the pages of a table in storage order.

Comment: Dropping is not possible by design of the DB. User will have no rights to perform DROP of any kind.

Comment: @kitet You can create a stored procedure which drops/re creates and then grant execute permission over that procedure.

Comment: Could you try a `DELETE FROM SZAFKI ORDER BY ID` (for `ID` substitute whatever your primary key is). I don't expect it to be faster, but you never know.

Comment: Another thing to try would be `DELETE FROM SZAFKI WHERE ID > 0` (assuming ids are 1 or higher). Is this BTW a table where the rows are updated, deleted and inserted a lot before final deletion; when I delete on a table with 200K records (freshly filled, so no garbage and no fragmentation of the datapages), it completes within 1.5 seconds.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel That's IT ! Delete, where ID > 0, 3 seconds! I was like WTF? Thanks, Mark!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Answer based on my comment*

A trick you could try is to use `DELETE FROM SZAFKI WHERE ID > 0` (assuming the `ID` is 1 or higher). This will force Firebird to look up the rows using the primary key index.

My initial assumption was that this would be worse than an unindexed delete. An unindexed delete will do a sequential scan of all datapages of a table and delete rows (that is: create a new recordversion that is a deleted stub record). When you use the index it will lookup rows in index order, this will result in a random walk through the datapages (assuming a high level of fragmentation in the data due to a high number of record versions due to inserts, deletes and updates). I had expected this to be slower, but probably it will result in Firebird having to only read the relevant datapages (with record versions relevant to the transaction) instead of all datapages of a table.

Comment: I don't know about any Firebird innards and how it processes data, though i should, probably, but anyway this works. Commit doesn't take any prolonged time in my case, as WarmBooter suggested, so i will accept this unexpected solution.

Comment: The commit itself won't take long, but the next select on the table could trigger garbage collection (actually removing old record versions that are no longer of interest to any transaction), and that could be a performance hit.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no fast way to do massive delete on entire (big) table with currently Firebird versions. You can expect even higher delays when the "deleted content" is garbage collected (run select * in the table after the delete is committed and you will see). You can try to deactivate indexes in that table before doing the delete and see if it helps.
If you are using the table as some kind of temporary storage, I suggest you to use the GTT feature.

Comment: No temp tables, just emptying many of them and filling them up again once a few weeks. Ding this takes long on my i7, so someone who uses my app on a possibly old laptop must be frustrated. I'm trying to cut times operation by operation, testing and so on, so that i don't have to deal with unexpected failures on their end, and, well... look good :D

Answer (score 0):

**Fastest** and only way to dot get rid from **all data fast** in FireBird table- **drop** and **create** table again. At least for the current official version 2.5.X . There is no truncate operator in roadmap for FireBird 3.0 , beta is out, so most probably no truncate in 3.0 too.

Also, you can use the operator **RECREATE** - same syntax as create. If table exists, RECRATE drops it, then creates new. If table doesn't exists, then recreate just creates it.

```
 RECREATE TABLE Table1 (
   ID    INTEGER,
   NAME  VARCHAR(20),
   DATE  DATE,
   T     TIME
 );
```

Comment: is there way to recreate without columns description(w/o any changes)?